# Prevent browser from keeping iframe url when reloading the parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, reload

I have a form inside an iframe. As soon as the user saved the data I redirect the iframe to a page that does nothing more than reloading the main page (as some other content depends on what was inserted inside the iframe). So the data outside the iframe ist updated and the form should appear again.

The problem: at least firefox (haven't tested it in other browsers yet) keeps the "new" url of the iframe with the redirected page and not the one that is set by sourcecode. Something similar to autocompletion with input fields.

I do the reload by

```
parent.location.reload();
```

Is there maybe a way to force a real reload without keeping any information from the history of the containing iframes?

btw: I may use jQuery if it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It is pretty funny but doing the reload by

```
parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
```

makes a fresh reload of the page without keeping the history. Haven't tested it in other browsers though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along these lines (http://jsfiddle.net/AKykZ/):

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('iframe').setAttribute('src', document.querySelector('iframe').getAttribute('src'));
    window.top.location.reload();
    return false;
}, false);
```

In the fiddle, click the link in the iframe, and hit the reload button. It sounds like you're reloading from the iframe, but this should at least get you on the right track.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It sets the src to the current src so shouldn't change anything. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you click the link in the iframe, and hit the reload, it goes back to the original `src`, as that doesn't get updated within the html.

Comment: Ah ok, I gonna give it a try

Comment: unfortunately doesn't solve it. The src is the correct one when I alert it (the form-url) but when the reload is finished, the iframe still has the reload-url loaded. It's probably a feature :)

Comment: You could try to do the reload when the load event for the iframe fires? Otherwise I'm out of ideas until I decide to make my own demo... :)

Comment: Found it, but it's ridiculous. Your answer gave me an idea. The same thing occurs if I press F5 and do the browser reload but if I press enter in the address bar it does a correct reload. So i switched my reload to parent.location.href = parent.location.href This is so senseless but it works ;)

Comment: Awesome. Glad you found the answer.